# Call angularJS function on md-select change

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularJS and want to call a function after change a md-select. Below is my code :

```
 <md-select ng-model="selectedSector" aria-label="select" onchange="filterCompanyList();">
       <md-option ng-repeat="sector in sectors" value="{{sector.value}}"> {{sector.name}} </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

AngularJS :

```
    function filterCompanyList() {
        alert(1);
    };
    $scope.filterCompanyList = filterCompanyList;
```

I want to call "filterCompanyList()" every time when I change md-option. But its not working. How can I do it? I am unable to find my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

From

```
onchange="filterCompanyList();"
```

To

```
ng-change="filterCompanyList();"
```

and

```
$scope.filterCompanyList = function() {
    alert(1);
};
```

Comment: But `onchange` also need to be hit the function. correct?

Comment: @RameshRajendran no it wont

Comment: Yes I know it won't. But he wrote a normal function `    function filterCompanyList() {
        alert(1);
    };
` why it's not hit?

Comment: @Ikr.ofc . Yup  that sound make sense. :)

Comment: @lkr.ofc yes right! mark as answer if it has helped